# How to sort a array of tuple if the tuple is a pre-defined class without implement comparator in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, tuples

I have a pre-defined tuple class which cannot be modified as follows:

```
public class Tuple {
    protected String name; 
    public Tuple(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have another class which defines an array of the above tuple:

```
public class Stack {
    protected ArrayList<Tuple> tupleLst; 
    public Stack(){
        this.tupleLst=new ArrayList<Tuple>(10);
    }
}
```

Then I need to sort the array of tuple in another class: for instance:

```
public class Algo {
    public static int Sort(Relation r){

    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
    Algo.Sort();
}
```

The Relation r is the input array of tuples. I have searched online, where I saw many people actually are using Comparators and Collections.sort() to do that. However, after I tried, I noticed that the Tuple class need to implement comparators in order to sort. How can I sort the tuple without changing the first two classes? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question should be: why won't you change the first two classes?

Comment: You are wrong: `Comparator` is a separate strategy interface. You don't have to touch your classes.

Answer (score 3):

Although `Tuple` cannot be modified, you can implement a `Comparator` of your own and then pass it to the `Collections.sort()` method (which will do a sort of your collection of tuples based on the comparator rule(s). For example:

```
Comparator<Tuple> myComparator = new Comparator<Tuple>() {
    public int compare(Tuple t1, Tuple t2) {
        //the comparison rules go here
    }
};
Collections.sort(tupleList, myComparator);
```

If you use Java8, you can achieve this in a single line:

```
myList.sort((t1, t2) -> { <comparison rules implementation> });
```

or (thanks to @MarkoTopolnik)

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(t -> <<get sort key from t>>)
```

Comment: Even simpler: `sort(Comparator.comparing(t -> <<get sort key from t>>)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing two methods. One way is to make your Tuple class implement the Comparable interface. I think this is the one you want to avoid since it seems you don't want to modify the Tuple class.

The other way is to define a new class, whose purpose is to compare two Tuples. This is what is called a Comparator. If you pass your list of Tuples and an instance of this comparator then you can sort your Tuples any way you like without modifying the Tuple class.